# Color coding using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I've created 2 scatterplots using data from a csv file on UK cities however need to color code the points based on their location. Within the csv file is a column titled 'region', which distinguishes which region they're in. Any way how I go about this?

Unsure of how to go about this.

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible dataset to better answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

With `UK.csv` as follows

```
1.2 3.4 5
6.5 3.2 3
```

the following code

```
...
x,y,reg = (np.array(v,dtype=t) for v, t in zip(
              zip(*(l.split() for l in open('UK.csv'))),
              (float, float, int)))

for n in set(reg):
    plt.scatter(x[reg==n], y[reg==n], label=str(n))

plt.legend(title='Region')
plt.show()
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since no description of the dataset is given. I am assuming:

1. CSV file - 'uk_cities.csv'
2. CSV file contains the geographical location or coordinates of these cities.

Below is the code snippet for the same.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Read CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv('uk_cities.csv')
    
    # Dictionary to map each region to a unique color
    region_color_map = {
        region_1: 'blue',
        region_2: 'green',
        region_3: 'red' # U can add more as per requirement
    }
    
    # Create a new column in the DataFrame with the assigned color as per the region
    df['color'] = df['city'].map(region_color_map)
    
    # Scatterplot the colored points
    plt.scatter(df['latitude'], df['longitude'], c=df['color'])
    
    # Add a legend with the color codes and region names
    plt.legend(handles=[plt.scatter([], [], c=color, label=region) for region, color in region_color_map.items()])
    
    plt.show()
```

Above code results in the following scatterplot.

For the ease of explanation; my CSV file only has 3 columns - (city, latitude, & longitude)

[image]